# react-native mapbox is not showing user location and annotation

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, mapbox, mapbox-android

I am currently learning react-native with maps using `mapbox`  https://github.com/mapbox/react-native-mapbox-gl  I followed everything that the map shows, if I give it a `lon` and `lat` it does show a location on my `emulator` but the problem is the `annotation` and `show user location` doesn't show at all.

Does anyone have any idea what I might be missing?
I have been rebuilding the app a few times and checked debugging that there is no errors though

here is my simple code

```
export default class App extends Component {
    data = [
      { id: '' }
    ];

    render() {
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Mapbox.MapView
            showUserLocation={true}
            styleURL={Mapbox.StyleURL.Street}
            zoomLevel={16}
            centerCoordinate={[-123.1118716, 49.2847564]}
            style={styles.container}>
          </Mapbox.MapView>
          <Mapbox.PointAnnotation
            id='1'
            title='nooooooooooooooooooooo'
            coordinate={[-123.1118716, 49.2847560]}
          >
          </Mapbox.PointAnnotation>
        </View>
      );
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Ran into the same issue, on Android >=23 you have to ask for permissions first

```
import { PermissionsAndroid } from 'react-native';
...
componentDidMount() {
{
 PermissionsAndroid.requestMultiple(
            [PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
            PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION],
            {
                title: 'Give Location Permission',
            message: 'App needs location permission to find your position.'
        }
    ).then(granted => {
        console.log(granted);
        resolve();
    }).catch(err => {
        console.warn(err);
        reject(err);
    });
}
```